# Weird blank space when drawing standalone tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I am drawing an `tikz` picture using `standalone` class, but there is weird blank space on the left side. My code is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  gold/.style = {
    top color=gray!60, 
    bottom color=gray!20, 
    minimum width=0.25cm, 
    minimum height=2cm, 
    anchor=west,
  },
  boron/.style = {
    top color=gray!80, 
    bottom color=gray!40,
    minimum width=1cm, 
    minimum height=2cm, 
    anchor=west,
  },
  telescope/.style = {
    right color=black!70, 
    left color=black!20,
    minimum width=1.2cm,
    minimum height=.4cm,
    sloped,
    pos=1,
    rotate=90,
  },
  E/.style = {
     top color=black!80, 
     bottom color=black!40,
     minimum width=1.2cm,
     minimum height=1.4cm, 
     sloped,
     pos=1,
     rotate=90,
   },
}

 \begin{tikzpicture}

  \coordinate (beam left) at (-5,0);
  \coordinate (beam right) at (2,0);

  % Incident Beam
  \draw[->, very thick] (beam left) -- (beam right);
  \node[above right] at (beam left) (proton) {$p^+$};

  % Target : Boron + Au
  \node[gold, label=95:$Au$] at (6,0) (gold) {};% Au
  \node[boron, right=0mm of gold, label=80:$^{nat}B$] (boron) {};

  \coordinate (hit) at (gold.west);

  % Telescopes
  \path (hit) -- +(170:8) 
        node[telescope, label=right:$6\mu m$] (telescope1) {$\Delta E$};
  \path (hit) -- +(-120:8)
        node[telescope, label=left:$22\mu m$] (telescope2) {$\Delta E$};
  \path (hit) -- +(170:9)
        node[E, label=20:$1000\mu m$] {$\mathbf{E}$};
  \path (hit) -- +(-120:9)
        node[E, label=left:$1000\mu m$]  {$\mathbf{E}$};

  % Angles
  \draw[dashed, gray, thick] (beam right) -- (hit);
  \draw[dashed, gray, thick] (hit) -- (telescope1);
  \draw[dashed, gray, thick] (hit) -- (telescope2);
  \draw[<->,thick] (hit)  +(180:2) arc (180:170:2);
  \path (hit) +(175:2) node[left] {$10^\circ$};
  \draw[<->,thick] (hit) +(180:2) arc (-180:-120:2);
  \path (hit) +(210:2) node[left] {$60^\circ$};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My output is the following

[image]

Any idea on why this is happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary` should go before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @egreg : You are right and that was the problem... Why did this happen?

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary` takes up horizontal space I guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a minimalistic example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{} A
\end{document}
```

[image]

This shows that the space between `\tikzset{}` and `A` is not ignored. It would be the same for

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{}
A
\end{document}
```

So you have several of these spurious spaces, because `tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex` starts with

```
\tikzset{above/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south}{0}{1}{north}{1}}
\tikzset{above left/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{south east}{-1}{1}{north west}{0.707106781}}
```

and so on for several lines.

The fact is that `standalone` puts TeX in LR mode (horizontal mode in proper TeX language), so spaces are not ignored.

You don't get any space if you add the `varwidth` option to `standalone`:

```
\usepackage[varwidth]{standalone}
```

(but you get an overfull box warning, because of the picture size).

Load libraries and do `\tikzset` commands before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 7):

If you put a `\fbox{}` around your `tikzpicture` you get:

> [image: Result]

Which shows that the extra space is not inside the tikzpicture. So it has to be produced by the code which is before it.

If you move `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` to the preamble, as egreg suggested in a comment, you get now:

> [image: Result2]

Which still has a (very small) gap to the left. This is due to the `\tikzset` settings, I'm not sure why (even removing all blank lines, this gap remains).

Moving `\tikzset` also to the preamble gives the desired result.